# Whirlpool in common crypto hashing library for python

Tags: python, whirlpool

Is there some common (recommended) module for generating hashes in Python?

In particular I need `whirlpool` but something like `mhash` extension in PHP or `jacksum` in java, where many hashing algorithms present, would be the ideal, so it could be used in future.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: In my system there is no `whirlpool` in `hashlib.algorithms`. May it be extended by some common means or no way?

Comment: Do you *need* whirlpool?

Comment: Yes, I need `whirlpool`.

Comment: Seems my question parted into two. As it titled "Common crypto hashing..." I suggest Marcelo Cantos to add his comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: @dmitry: I supplied the link as a comment since it didn't address the whirlpool aspect. Ignacio's answer is probably as good as you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+whirlpool) finds both a [pure Python implementation](http://www.bjrn.se/code/whirlpoolpy.txt) as well as a [binding written in C](https://github.com/radiosilence/python-whirlpool) for the Whirlpool algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I began searching for a *common* way to do it, being suggesting that it exists. Seems not.

Answer (score 0):

I use the librhash ( [examples here](https://github.com/rhash/RHash/blob/master/bindings/python/test_rhash.py) ). There you has a lot of hash algorithms, included Whirlpool. And it available in the most popular distributions like [ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-rhash&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)